# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el programa borre solo las filas que yo quiero y no toda la pantalla?

Tags: c, windows, consola

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("hola esta linea no la quiero borrar");
  printf("\nesta tampoco quiero borrarla");
  printf("\nquiero que el programa me borre esta linea");
  printf("\nquiero que el programa me borre tambien esta linea");
  Sleep(50000);
}
```

Comment: Sin el uso de bibliotecas específicas para manejo de la terminal, la solución más simple consiste en borrar la pantalla entera y luego "repintar" (volver a imprimir) las líneas que querías conservar, e imprimir un retorno de carro en las que querías borrar.

Comment: y en cuanto a las bibliotecas especificas cuales habría que poner y que comando. No me importa utilizar otras bibliotecas

Comment: En el mundo unix se utiliza `curses`. No existen que yo sepa portes para Windows (sin contar cygwin, que usa su propio compilador gcc). Para windows nativo tienes la [API de la consola](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/). Ni curses ni la console api son cosas triviales. Más bien diría lo contrario. Aún sin tener experiencia real de su uso, me parecen enormemente complejas, y pensadas para hacer interfaces de usuario complejas en modo texto. Vamos, que yo en tu lugar no iría por ahí, para un asunto tan trivial como este.

Comment: a el ejemplo que he puesto es muy simple era para que se entendiera pero era para implementarlo a una calculadora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una alternativa al uso de complicadas bibliotecas para el manejo de la terminal, puede ser el utilizar *códigos de escape ANSI*, que son un estándar utilizado por muchas terminales, entre ellas la consola Windows (y muchas terminales Unix, por lo que esta solución tiene la ventaja de funcionar en ambos).

Estos *códigos de escape* son ciertas secuencias de caracteres que comienzan por unos bytes especiales que la pantalla reconoce como "instrucciones", y según qué caracteres vayan detrás le indican que debe hacer cosas como "subir  n líneas el cursor", "borrar la línea actual", etc.

La secuencia especial de bytes que inicia estas instrucciones es el código "escape" (ASCII 27, o bien `1b` en hexadecimal) seguida del carácter `[`.

En cuanto a las letras que van después de esas, y lo que significa cada una, tienes una referencia en [la documentación de la consola de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences)

En concreto para tu caso, podemos usar la secuencia "subir dos líneas el cursor", que sería `"2A"`, y después "borrar dos líneas desde la posición actual", que sería `"2M"`.

Para enviar esas secuencias especiales a la pantalla podemos usar un simple `printf()`, por lo que el código de ejemplo sería

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CSI "\x1b["      // Lo definimos para no tener que teclearlo

int main()
{
  printf("hola esta linea no la quiero borrar\n");
  printf("esta tampoco quiero borrarla\n");
  printf("quiero que el programa me borre esta linea\n");
  printf("quiero que el programa me borre tambien esta linea\n");
  Sleep(50000);

  printf(CSI "2A");
  printf(CSI "2M\n");
}
```

Comment: he probado el codigo que me has ofrecido y no borra ninguna de las lineas que salen por pantalla. Hay que añadir algo esq no lo habia utilizado nunca eso